# magento 2 third party extension model override issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, third-party-module

By using preference I am overriding third party (custom built extension) model class. For the process I have added `di.xml` file as shown below.

**Path: Test/Test/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper" type="Test\Test\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper" />
</config>
```

Below represants code of the file which is extending the third part extension model class. In this file function "cartFactory" is inside class - 
`\ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper`.

But it raise an error saying :

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Test\Test\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper::$cartFactory in
>   app/code/Test/Test/Model/Carrier/Processor/ShipperMapper.php on line
>   41

**Path:** `app/code/Test/Test/Model/Carrier/Processor/ShipperMapper.php`

```
namespace Test\Test\Model\Carrier\Processor;

class ShipperMapper extends \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper
{
    /**
     * Format cart for from shipper for Magento
     *
     * @param $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCartDetails($request)
    {
        $cartDetails = $this->cartFactory->create([
            'declaredValue' => $request->getPackageValue(),
            'freeShipping'  => (bool)$request->getFreeShipping(),
            'items'         => $this->getFormattedItems($request, $request->getAllItems())
        ]);

        //My custom code is here

        return $cartDetails;
    }
}
```

Parent model file Code
**Path:** `app/code/ShipperHQ/Shipper/Model/Carrier/Processor/ShipperMapper.php`

```
<?php
namespace ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor;

/**
 * Class Shipperhq_Shipper_Model_Carrier_Convert_ShipperMapper
 *
 * This class converts the Magento Request into a format that
 * is usable by the ShipperHQ webservice
 */
use ShipperHQ\WS;
use ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request;


class ShipperMapper
{

    protected static $ecommerceType = 'magento';
    protected static $stdAttributeNames = [
        'shipperhq_shipping_group', 'shipperhq_post_shipping_group',
        /* 'shipperhq_warehouse',*/ 'shipperhq_royal_mail_group', 'shipperhq_shipping_qty',
        'shipperhq_shipping_fee', 'shipperhq_additional_price', 'freight_class',
        'shipperhq_nmfc_class', 'shipperhq_nmfc_sub', 'shipperhq_handling_fee', 'shipperhq_carrier_code',
        'shipperhq_volume_weight', 'shipperhq_declared_value', 'ship_separately',
        'shipperhq_dim_group', 'shipperhq_poss_boxes', 'ship_box_tolerance', 'must_ship_freight', 'packing_section_name'
    ];

    protected static $dim_height = 'ship_height';
    protected static $dim_width = 'ship_width';
    protected static $dim_length = 'ship_length';
    protected static $alt_height = 'height';
    protected static $alt_width = 'width';
    protected static $alt_length = 'length';
    protected static $origin = 'shipperhq_warehouse';
    protected static $location = 'shipperhq_location';
    protected static $available_date = 'shipperhq_availability_date';

    protected static $useDefault = 'Use Default';

    protected static $dim_group = 'shipperhq_dim_group';
    protected static $conditional_dims = ['shipperhq_poss_boxes',
        'shipperhq_volume_weight', 'ship_box_tolerance', 'ship_separately', 'ship_height', 'ship_width', 'ship_length',
        'height', 'width', 'length'
    ];

    protected static $legacyAttributeNames = [
        'package_id', 'special_shipping_group', 'volume_weight', 'warehouse', 'handling_id',
        'package_type' // royal mail
    ];

    protected static $shippingOptions = ['liftgate_required', 'notify_required', 'inside_delivery', 'destination_type'];

    protected static $prodAttributes;

    /**
     * @var \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $shipperDataHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory
     */
    private $groupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata
     */
    private $productMetadata;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation
     */
    private $taxCalculation;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration
     */
    private $productConfiguration;
    /**
     * @var Request\RateRequestFactory
     */
    private $rateRequestFactory;
    /**
     * @var \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist
     */
    private $shipperLogger;
    /**
     * @var Request\Shipping\SelectedOptionsFactory
     */
    private $selectedOptionsFactory;
    /*
     * @var \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory
     */
    private  $cartFactory;
    /*
     * @var \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\Item
     */
    private $itemFactory;
    /**
     * @var WS\Shared\AddressFactory
     */
    private $addressFactory;
    /**
     * @var Request\InfoRequestFactory
     */
    private $infoRequestFactory;
    /**
     * @var WS\Shared\CredentialsFactory
     */
    private $credentialsFactory;
    /**
     * @var WS\Shared\SiteDetailsFactory
     */
    private $siteDetailsFactory;
    /**
     * @var Request\CustomerDetailsFactory
     */
    private $customerDetailsFactory;
    /**
     * @var Request\ShipDetailsFactory
     */
    private $shipDetailsFactory;
    /**
     * @var StockHandler
     */
    protected $stockHandler;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var  \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\PhysicalBuildingDetailFactory
     */
    protected $physicalBuildingDetailFactory;
    /**
     * @var  \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\StockDetailFactory
     */
    protected $stockDetailFactory;

    function __construct(\ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\Data $shipperDataHelper,
                         \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\RateRequestFactory $rateRequestFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\InfoRequestFactory $infoRequestFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\CredentialsFactory $credentialsFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\SiteDetailsFactory $siteDetailsFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\CustomerDetailsFactory $customerDetailsFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\ShipDetailsFactory $shipDetailsFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Shipping\SelectedOptionsFactory $selectedOptionsFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory $cartFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
                         \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
                         \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist $shipperLogger,
                         \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfiguration,
                         \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata $productMetadata,
                         \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
                         StockHandler $stockHandler,
                         \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\PhysicalBuildingDetailFactory $physicalBuildingDetailFactory,
                         \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\StockDetailFactory $stockDetailFactory
    )
    {

        $this->shipperDataHelper = $shipperDataHelper;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        self::$prodAttributes = $this->shipperDataHelper->getProductAttributes();
        $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
        $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata;
        $this->taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
        $this->productConfiguration = $productConfiguration;
        $this->rateRequestFactory = $rateRequestFactory;
        $this->shipperLogger = $shipperLogger;
        $this->selectedOptionsFactory = $selectedOptionsFactory;
        $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
        $this->infoRequestFactory = $infoRequestFactory;
        $this->credentialsFactory = $credentialsFactory;
        $this->siteDetailsFactory = $siteDetailsFactory;
        $this->customerDetailsFactory = $customerDetailsFactory;
        $this->shipDetailsFactory = $shipDetailsFactory;
        $this->stockHandler = $stockHandler;
        $this->physicalBuildingDetailFactory = $physicalBuildingDetailFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->stockDetailFactory = $stockDetailFactory;
    }

    /*Other function continue*/
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `private` variable of your extended class. If you can this using construct function.

Firstly add below variable.

```
/*
* @var \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory
*/
private  $cartFactory;
```

Then add `__construct` fucntion

```
function __construct(\ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory $cartFactory)
{
    $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending the original class, you can only access its public or protected variables. `$cartFactory` in the original class is private so you cant access it directly with

```
$this->cartFactory
```

The question here really is, if a preference is a good choice. If there is any other way around it shoudn't be used. It seems like a after plugin in your case would be a way better choice http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below override model

```
class ShipperMapper extends \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper
{

    private $cartFactory;

    public function __construct(\ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\Data $shipperDataHelper,
                             \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\RateRequestFactory $rateRequestFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\InfoRequestFactory $infoRequestFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\CredentialsFactory $credentialsFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\SiteDetailsFactory $siteDetailsFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\CustomerDetailsFactory $customerDetailsFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\ShipDetailsFactory $shipDetailsFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Shipping\SelectedOptionsFactory $selectedOptionsFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory $cartFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
                             \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
                             \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist $shipperLogger,
                             \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfiguration,
                             \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata $productMetadata,
                             \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
                             StockHandler $stockHandler,
                             \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\PhysicalBuildingDetailFactory $physicalBuildingDetailFactory,
                             \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\StockDetailFactory $stockDetailFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $shipperDataHelper,$groupFactory,$rateRequestFactory,$infoRequestFactory,$addressFactory,$credentialsFactory,
            $siteDetailsFactory,$customerDetailsFactory,$shipDetailsFactory,$selectedOptionsFactory,$cartFactory,$itemFactory,
            $taxCalculation,$shipperLogger,$productConfiguration,$productMetadata,$context,$stockHandler,$checkoutSession,
            $physicalBuildingDetailFactory,$stockDetailFactory
        );
         $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
    }

    // Custom code here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I have try but it's throw error.

Comment: what error it is throwing? I have missed comma in the constructor, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas Verma answer is right but magento throw error so i have pass parent construct on my construct function. Here is full code. Maybe it's helpful to other people.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Test\Model\Carrier\Processor;

class ShipperMapper extends \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\ShipperMapper
{
    /*
    * @var \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory
    */
    private $cartFactory;

    public function __construct(\ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\Data $shipperDataHelper,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\RateRequestFactory $rateRequestFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\InfoRequestFactory $infoRequestFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\CredentialsFactory $credentialsFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Shared\SiteDetailsFactory $siteDetailsFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\CustomerDetailsFactory $customerDetailsFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\ShipDetailsFactory $shipDetailsFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Shipping\SelectedOptionsFactory $selectedOptionsFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\CartFactory $cartFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
                                \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
                                \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist $shipperLogger,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfiguration,
                                \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata $productMetadata,
                                \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
                                \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Carrier\Processor\StockHandler $stockHandler,
                                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\PhysicalBuildingDetailFactory $physicalBuildingDetailFactory,
                                \ShipperHQ\WS\Rate\Request\Checkout\StockDetailFactory $stockDetailFactory
    )
    {
        $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;

        parent::__construct($shipperDataHelper,
            $groupFactory,
            $rateRequestFactory,
            $infoRequestFactory,
            $addressFactory,
            $credentialsFactory,
            $siteDetailsFactory,
            $customerDetailsFactory,
            $shipDetailsFactory,
            $selectedOptionsFactory,
            $cartFactory,
            $itemFactory,
            $taxCalculation,
            $shipperLogger,
            $productConfiguration,
            $productMetadata,
            $context,
            $stockHandler,
            $checkoutSession,
            $physicalBuildingDetailFactory,
            $stockDetailFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Format cart for from shipper for Magento
     *
     * @param $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCartDetails($request)
    {
        $cartDetails = $this->cartFactory->create([
                'declaredValue' => $request->getPackageValue(),
                'freeShipping'  => (bool)$request->getFreeShipping(),
                'items'         => $this->getFormattedItems($request, $request->getAllItems())
        ]);

        return $cartDetails;
    }
}
```